# WPF C# GridSplitter on DragCompleted

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to add a functionality on GridSplitter1.DragComplete. Here is the code:

```
     int gridCol0Width = (int)((sender as GridSplitter).Parent as Grid).ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value;
```

The code will get the `sender as GridSplitter` and the `Parent as Grid` how can I accomplish this code without having the `sender` defined on the code. Here is my code:

```
   gridCol0Width = (int)(gridSplitter1.Parent as Grid).ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value;
```

The way this code is written, the code does not work properly. I get width values of 1. How can I fix the code?

Comment: Have you tried behaviors?

Comment: have u tried actualwidth instead of width?